# FQL request to facebook from Unity3D

Tags: c#, facebook, get, facebook-fql, unity-game-engine

I need to send a GET request to Facebook from unity3d and retrieve it's answer (JSON object). I do it well in Visual Studio with WebRequest. But as far as I know, WebRequest class is not supported in iOS. So I'm trying to accomplish this with Unity's standart WWW class. Doing as follows:

```
public static IEnumerator GETRequestToFacebook()
{
    WWW www = new WWW("https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select name from profile where id=707855857");

    yield return www;

    Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

But that method gives me the following error: *"You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading. 400 Bad Request"*. But if I change url to "http://www.google.com" it works just fine.

What should I do to make my initial GET request work in unity3d?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I should have put '+' signs in a FQL request.

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+name+from+profile+where+id=707855857"

Nevermind, I've already written a web socket.